# How to: Fix ReactJS Type Errror - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working with a material-ui header component and I am running into this error :

What should I look at to debug this first? Focusing on web-development again and struggling with little things.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined


src/Components/Header.js:53


  50 |     Sign up
  51 |   </Button>
  52 | </Toolbar>
> 53 | <Toolbar component="nav" variant="dense" className={classes.toolbarSecondary}>
     | ^  54 |   {sections.map((section) => (
  55 |     <Link
  56 |       color="inherit"
```

Comment: The error is `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, so you're trying to `.map` something that's `undefined`. Look at your code, what are you trying to `.map`?

Comment: either sections are undefined or sections is not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this, take a look at the error: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` 
JavaScript is telling you that somewhere (the stack trace usually tells you in what line) you tried to to read the property `map` on an object that is `undefined` 
Take a look at this snippet, which will throw the same error:

```
let sections; // sections= undefined
sections.map();
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a function coming from [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) which means you need to invoke it on an array:

```
const sections = [1,2,3];
sections.map(...);
// works, because sections is an array.
```

---

To be more specific about your code, `sections` variable is undefined and not an array, as you probably expect it to be. 
What you can do is one of:

1. use [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) pattern:

   `sections && sections.map(...)`
2. Initialize sections to an empty array.

Both will probably work. Decide which one is the right solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use optional Chaining of javascript
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

`sections?.map`

even if sections is undefined, it won't throw error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `sections` is undefined at the time of render (probably because of asynchronous behaviour). You can fix this by using a ternary operator -

`condition ? truthy expression : falsy expression`

```
{ sections.length ? sections.map((section) => <Link color="inherit" ...
   : <p class="errorMsg"> No sections can be displayed. </p>
```